# Free search text in devtool extension panel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am looking for a way to search text in a Chrome Devtools Panel Extension for an extension I wrote. The panel is a standard web application (js, css, html).
Currently when I hit `cmd + f` a search bar pops at the bottom of the extension panel.
In the example below I expect that the word `Hello` will be highlighted, but this kind of behaviour is probably not supported OOB by Chrome Devtools panels.
Is there any way to implement this kind of behaviour in my extension code (by binding to special events, or configuration)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to implement that functionality manually. However, I know that there is an event listener for triggering a search event for the chrome.devtools.panels api.

It would be implemented like so:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("My devtools extension",
"logo.png",
"page.html",
function(panel) {
    panel.onShown.addListener(function(event) {
        ...
    });

    panel.onHidden.addListener(function(event) {
        ...
    });

    panel.onSearch.addListener(function(event) {
        <your code here>
    });
});
```

This way, you could implement this functionality any way you want.

Here is a link for more about Chrome panels: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you know how to tell Chrome how many hits your search found - which enables the next and previous buttons?